# Extracting BNF data in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm studying Isabelle's encoding of (co)datatypes. I was wondering if there is a way of defining a datatype, say:

```
datatype 'a tree = Node 'a ('a tree fset)
```

and then inspecting the BNF it generates.

Comment: You can use the command `print_bnfs`. Moreover, of course, you can see all generated theorems by using `print_theorems` immediately after the definition of the datatype. Perhaps, if you need further insight, you could try exploring the ML infrastructure associated with the BNFs.

Comment: thanks @user9716869, I wonder how you came up with this command. Is there a command showing all the "printing commands"? Or you rather looked somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: There is a command that can print all available commands: `print_commands`. Also,  sometimes, I rely on autocompletion. Of course, reading the documentation is nearly always the best way to find what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `print_bnfs`. Moreover, of course, you can see all generated theorems by using `print_theorems` immediately after the definition of the datatype. Perhaps, if you need further insight, you could try exploring the ML infrastructure associated with the BNFs.

As a side note, it is possible to see a list of all available commands using the command `print_commands`.